# use state after setState on the same function deatils not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

hello i have a problem with my code
i have function that  filter the state of users (users is the state that contain all the users that added)
but i need on the same onclick event that
1 i will delete the current object from the array (and i did it correctly)

2 to get this users and count all the number after the delete

but when i go to
users forEach it not getting the updated state and get the old one only the second click will update..
so after deleteFlight function execute its update the users without the current number
but when i start to use user.forEach it not give me the update state

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const deleteFlight = (num) => {
    const afterFilter = users.filter((user) => {
      return user.numFlight !== num;
    });
    
     setUsers(afterFilter);
     alert("deleted")
  };
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const inp = numFlightInp.current.value;

          deleteFlight(Number(inp));

          users.forEach((user) => {
            passengerCnt += user.passenger;
            totalFlightCnt++;
          });
          setFlightCnt2(totalFlightCnt);
          setPassengerCnt2(passengerCnt);

          if (!checkDuplicateFlight(Number(inp))) return alert("not found match");
        }}
      >
        delete
      </button>
```

Comment: Flight and passenger count properly shouldn't be states at all. They should be *derived* from state, using `useMemo`.

Comment: hey
i am new to react
can you explain it to begginer?
or you can show me how it should be?
i need them to be state because i need them to update on evrey click
please guide me

Comment: `users` already updates on every click, right? Just count them every time you render.

Comment: you mean by using useeffect the evrey render it will forEach on users?
because i try iy and i have an issue with this solution
when i go to this page of delete it start the useeffect because it on a diffrent componente
but after i click delete it again run this useeffect and it mean that it double the result 

or that i aint using it right or that  i didnt understand you correctly

Comment: I said `useMemo`, not `useEffect`. Or just no hook at all, put the `forEach` (and the var declarations) right after the `const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);`.

Comment: first of all thank you so much for this solution and it worked!
now i need to understand a few things
the only change that i make
is not use foreach on this deleteFlight compononte is to make the foreach on users at the App.js
but!
i try before to create a function and inside that function i create foreach and it still didnt work
maybe it was because the counter was a state?